# Extract list of randomly sized triangles fully covering a rectangular space in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on a python project which requires me to divide a rectangular space in to triangles.

1. There can be no overlap or spaces between the triangles.
2. All of the rectangles area has to be filled.
3. ***Ideally*** the angles and the sizes of the triangles should differ from
   each other in a ***random*** fashion.
4. The algorithm should return a list of all triangles as tuples of
   their three corner coordinates.

*I am requesting an algorithm to solve the above.*

**Things I have tried.**

I have looked for packages and algorithms that might help me but haven't found any.

So far, I've thought about creating one random triangle at a time following the top border but get stuck when I reach the opposite vertical border. I don't how to continue from there while making sure that no space is left without a triangle.

I also thought about just drawing random lines from border to border, but I can't figure out how to find all the triangles created by their intersections as well as guaranteeing that all subareas are triangles.

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

---

Comment: For package, I recommend ```sympy```.

Comment: A practical way to do this is to add some randomly positioned points within the rectangle, and then do a Delaunay triangulation of all the points, including the rectangle corners: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Comment: I find this question adequately asks for an algorithm to divide a rectangle into unequal triangles. Why was it closed??

Comment: Hi @Jesper, I edited your question in a hope to get it reopened. Ihope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you @paddy3118, I don't mind at all! I'm going to try solving it with the feedback I've gotten so far, but if it gets reopened more feedback/discussion would always be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you think of drawing a diagonal across the rectangle, you have achieved your objective for 2 triangles, each being half of the rectangle area.

For multiple triangles, start at any one of the corners, draw a line from it to a random point on the opposite (not adjacent) side. Use that point to draw another line to a point on the original side (increasing the X position as you go).

The final line drawn must meet the opposite corner on the original side.

Save the coordinates of each triangle as 3 tuples. The first tuple of the first triangle, for example, may be {0,0}, depending on the point numbering nomenclature of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm**

Think of a rectangle lying, without rotation, on a plane. Lets name the corners A, B, C, and D like this:

```
A        B

D        C
```

Add one point, `p` between-but-not-equal-to A and B giving

```
A p      B

D        C
```

Create the two extra lines D-p and p-C creating 3 triangles A-p-D, D-p-C and p-B-C. Now if distances A-p, p-B and B-C are all different, then the triangles will be different.

If we instead inserted **two** points between A-B, p0 and p1, we can insert **one** point q0, along D-C

```
  0  1
A p  p   B
  
D   q    C
    0
```

We think of the L-to-R ordered top points as A p0 p1 then B; and the ordered l-to-R bottom points as D q0 then C.

- Create the triangles by using the i'th, (i+1)'th top points and the i'th bottom point; alternating with the (i)'th (i+1)'th bottom point and the (i+1)'th top point.
- Ensure the distances between successive top points, B-C, and successive bottom points are all different to get different triangles.
- If you insert `n`top points p, then you need `n-1` bottom points q.

I would randomly divide A-B n times, and D-C n-1 times; then redo this if all the distances aren't different to your required precision.

You didn't ask for code, but the points A B C and D help with the explanation, above, but if I were coding this I would use two arrays P and Q where

```
P[0] = A; P[max_p] = B; Q[0] = D; Q[max_p] = C;
P[i+1] = p[i]; Q[i+1] = q[i]
```

That would ease the creation of triangles.

**Code**

Here's some Python I wrote:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
For: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385109/extract-list-of-randomly-sized-triangles-fully-covering-a-rectangular-space-in-p/70390360#70390360


Created on Fri Dec 17 08:47:03 2021

@author: paddy
"""
import random
from typing import List, Union, Tuple


# Types
Num = Union[int, float]
Point = Tuple[Num, Num]


def rect_into_tri(
        top_right: Tuple[Num, Num] = (2, 1), # assuming bottom_left is at 0,0
        triangles: int             = 5,      # Odd number > 2
        _rand_tol: Num             = 1e6,    # Sets max random divisions of rectange width
        ) -> List[Tuple[Point, Point, Point]]:
    """
    Divide Rectangle into triangles number of non-similar triangles that 
    exactly cover the rectangles area.

    Parameters
    ----------
    top_right : Tuple[Num, Num], optional
        Rectangle bottom-left is (0, ). The default is (2, 1).
    triangles : int, optional
        Number of triangles created. An odd number > 2. The default is 5.
    _rand_tol : Num, optional
        Sets max random divisions of rectange width. The default is 1e6.

    Returns
    -------
    List[Tuple[Point, Point, Point]]
        A list of triangles; each of three points - of two numbers.

    """

    width, height = top_right
    assert triangles > 2 and triangles % 2 == 1, "Needs Odd number greater than 2"
    #assert triangles * 100 < _rand_tol, "Might not have enough tolerance to ensure disimilar triangles"
    
    _rand_tol = int(_rand_tol)
    
    #%% Point insertion
    insert_top = triangles // 2
    p = q = None
    while not p or not different_distances(p, q, height):
        p = [0] + rand_points(insert_top,     width, int(_rand_tol)) + [width]  # top points 
        q = [0] + rand_points(insert_top - 1, width, int(_rand_tol)) + [width]  # bottom points
    
    #%% Triangle extraction
    top_tri = [((t0, height), (t1, height), (b0, 0))
               for t0, t1, b0 in zip(p, p[1:], q)]
    bottom_tri = [((b0, 0), (b1, 0), (t1, height))
                  for b0, b1, t1 in zip(q, q[1:], p[1:])]
    
    return top_tri + bottom_tri

#%% Helpers
def rand_points(n: int, width: Num=1, _rand_tol: int=1_000_000) -> List[float]:
    "return n sorted, random points where 0 < point < width"
    return sorted(p * width / _rand_tol 
                  for p in random.sample(range(1, _rand_tol), n))
        
def different_distances(p: List[Num], q: List[Num], height: Num) -> bool:
    "Are all point-to-next-point distances in p and q; and height all different?"
    diffs =  [p1 - p0 for p0, p1 in zip(p, p[1:])]
    diffs += [q1 - q0 for q0, q1 in zip(q, q[1:])]
    diffs += [height]
    return len(diffs) == len(set(diffs))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pprint import pprint as pp
    
    pp(rect_into_tri((2, 1), 5, 10))
```

**Sample output**

```
[((0, 1), (0.2, 1), (0, 0)),
 ((0.2, 1), (0.8, 1), (0.4, 0)),
 ((0.8, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)),
 ((0, 0), (0.4, 0), (0.2, 1)),
 ((0.4, 0), (2, 0), (0.8, 1))]
```